# Abusing :target to style multiple elements

Tags: css

My goals:

- Generate a single HTML document with all my output so that it can be copied as a single unit.
- Have multiple "pages" within that document that display different parts of the data.
- Let the browser's back button do the Right Thing, and support deep-linking.

This is relatively easy to do using the :target pseudo-class to show only the page that I'm looking at (`div {display: none} :target {display: block}`).

I would like to add two refinements:

- A navigation bar that highlights the current page's name.
- A main page that appears when there is no fragment identifier (the thing after the `#`) in the URL.

I have created a solution using empty divs and sibling selectors. The target element (the element whose ID is in the URL fragment identifier) is an empty div, `target`, and then my CSS says `#target1 ~ #page1 { ... } #target1 ~ #link1 { ... }`. For a full example see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/645hxact/6/); note that after clicking on the links in the nav bar, the back and forwards browser buttons work as one might reasonably expect (I don't think it's possible to demonstrate deep-linking using jsfiddle).

There are three drawbacks to this solution:

- There is a separate selector in my CSS for each page, which can become unwieldy if there are many pages.
- The back button works on Chrome and Firefox, but Edge doesn't seem to like this (I haven't tested it anywhere else). My understanding is that [the spec is unclear](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/639) regarding `:target` and the back button (see also this [Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83490)).
- As the question's title says, it feels like I'm abusing... something.

My question is, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I have a slight preference for no JavaScript (mainly because that makes deep-linking more obviously correct).

Comment: If you know that there will always be a fixed number of elements between each empty div and its corresponding content div, you could cheat by using adjacent sibling selectors: `:target + * + * + * + * + div`. The drawback to *that* is having to add `+ *` as the number of pages increases, but it's not nearly as bad as adding entire complex selectors. Assuming JavaScript is not considered, it's a matter of picking whichever seems like the lesser evil to you.

Comment: If you don't want to feel like you're abusing anything, then, well, you're going to have to embrace JavaScript. The fact is that CSS doesn't have a way for you to associate the target element with an arbitrary element without prior knowledge of the target element's id. Also the interoperability issues that you've mentioned.

Comment: Aside from Edge, IE11 is not supporting it as well. Additionally Opera does support it to the point that it shows the correct page and browser back/forth is working, but it does not alter the address bar so copying links to a specific "page" of yours or bookmarking it will never work here (always loads the initial main page). --- So as @BoltClock said, you've reached the point where you need to start thinking about using JavaScript... --- BTW deep-linking is easily accomplish-able using a JS Router (a small simple one is this: http://work.krasimirtsonev.com/git/navigo/).

Answer (score 1):

@Seika85 linked (in a comment) to Navigo, a Javascript router that seems built to do exactly this. I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/645hxact/7/) to use that instead, which eliminates all the drawbacks I mentioned, at the (minor) expense of having to use (a small bit of) Javascript. Thanks!

```
new Navigo(null, false) 
.on(/target(.)/, function(x) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#page'+x).addClass('active');
  $('#link'+x).addClass('active');
})
```